# Magento 2: Composer Only Instalation

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to write up a tutorial explaining how to install Magento 2 **only** via composer, and use that tutorial as an in to exploring how third party composer repositories work.  Looking at the current Magento 2 development setup, there's a few pieces of information I'm missing and I hope the community can fill them in.

Specifically, the `composer.json` in the [Magento 2 GitHub repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/composer.json) lists the Magento package name as `magento/magento2ce`.  However, this package [does not exist in packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/magento/magento-composer-installer), nor does it exist in [packages.magento.com](http://packages.magento.com/#!/magento/magento2ce).

This means I can't just do a

```
composer require magento/magento2ce
```

and have Magento 2 automatically install.

Is there a Magento 2 provided package end-users can use to install that latest stable version of Magento two **without** checking out the source from GitHub?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things may change a bit before GA as we did things like supporting modules in 'vendor', and we have the "New Magento Connect" coming soon which includes a Composer repository. Just the perfect storm going on - trying to get everything landed together. But yes, there *will* be a single CE package you can depend on that will suck in CE. It will also include the patch level, so for people who want it simple, there will be a CE meta-package with patch level. To get CE patches, you just depend on the new patch level of the meta package, and you will get a combination of modules that has been run through all tests etc.

So it *will* be clean at GA, but is not quite there yet.  Note that packages.magento.com is a placeholder until the "New Connect" - it will go away after we have the "real" site up. (And no, I cannot give you a release date, but it is Real Soon Now™.)

Answer (score 3):

Right now you can install Magento from [this](https://packagist.org/packages/magento/project-community-edition) package on the Packagist:

`composer create-project --stability="alpha" magento/project-community-edition`

This is 1.0.0-beta version of Magento, which is couple of months old. During the release the repository may change, stability will change, but `composer create-project` command is the way to install it.

Comment: This method is discussed in the documentation: http://bit.ly/1hhqBpf

It will probably change at GA and if so, we'll update that page.

Answer (score 2):

To install Magento 2 via Composer, you have to visit [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/applications/customer/login) to get authentication keys. Click "My Access Keys" after logging in and generate new set of keys.

Enter the following command in terminal.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

Public key is your username and private key is your password.

Now you can install Magento through setup wizard.

To install it with sample data, navigate to your Magento 2 root directory and run the commands below.

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

These commands will update composer.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Magento 2 via composer, run the following command in the root directory to download it.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

Now run the following command to install Magento 2.

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url="http://yoururl.com/" 
--db-host="localhost" 
--db-name="dbname" 
--db-user="dbuser" 
--db-password="dbpass" 
--admin-firstname="admin" 
--admin-lastname="admin" 
--admin-email="user@example.com" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="admin123" 
--language="en_US" 
--currency="USD" 
--timezone="America/Chicago" 
--use-rewrites="1" 
--backend-frontname="admin"
```